# Symfony2: Update schema with dynamic entity manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

I have a problem with updating database schema. I have a entity manager for connect to database via db name when user logging. I have two databases - db1 and db2. I want to update schema for each databases. Is it possible in doctrine?

Comment: You can specify the entity manager when running doctrine:schema:update.  Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, you need multiple connections defined in your config.yml. Check here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html